# MQ Explorer --Queue Handle Status-- Handle State showing inactive

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am able to connect, pass the data to MQ , but not able to retrieve data from MQ. On some base level analysis I found out that the only difference between successful messages and unsuccessful one is the 'Handle State' column;

[image]

which is inactive for failed cases and 'Active' for successful cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Handle state shows 'Inactive' when the request text for that specific queue backend logic doesnot match the required syntax. It started to be in 'Active' once the data format was corrected

Answer (score 0):

Handle State indicates if an API call is in progress.  You would only see this as Active if the application has issued a GET with wait and the GET has not completed because no messages are available.  In the screen shot both handles show Input Shared, but only one has Output Yes, if the handle with Output Yes is the process putting to the queue then it would be normal for you to see the Handle State as Inactive.

Morag Hughson wrote a great blog on this subject that I would suggest you review:

[IBM MQ Little Gem #32: HSTATE](https://www.imwuc.org/blog/ibm-mq-little-gem-32-hstate)